# Angular 2 routing using LoadChildren

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing

I am using this code for routing

```
{ path: 'dashboard', loadChildren: './dashboard#DashboardModule'},
{ path: '', children: [     
   { path: '', component:DashboardComponent, children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo:'dashboard/first',pathMatch:'full' },
      { path: 'first', component: FirstComponent },
      { path: 'second', component: SecondComponent }]
   }, 
]},
```

Here when the url is `/dashboard` I need it to route to `/dashboard/first...`

How can I achieve it?

Comment: Try `redirectTo:'first'` instead of `redirectTo:'dashboard/first'`

Comment: where is it u say redirectTo:first instead of redirectTo:'dashboard/first'?

Comment: Errr... in the code you provided.

Comment: thanks buddy.. Did work..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are already in `Dashboard` component. Use only `first`, not `dashboard/first`.

```
 { path: '', children: [
    { path: '', component:DashboardComponent ,
        children:[
          { path: '', redirectTo:'first',pathMatch:'full' },
          { path: 'first', component: FirstComponent },
          { path: 'second', component: SecondComponent },
        ]  
     }, 
  ]},
```